# Symfony DomCrawler with XML and XPath

Tags: php, xml, symfony, xpath, domcrawler

I am trying to get all the `title` elements and save them in an array.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mylist>
    <element>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>Example 1</title>
        <status>2</status>
        <my_status>2</my_status>
    </element>
    <element>
        <id>2</id>
        <title>Example 2</title>
        <status>1</status>
        <my_status>1</my_status>
    </element>
    <element>
        <id>3</id>
        <title>Example 3</title>
        <status>2</status>
        <my_status>6</my_status>
    </element>
    <element>
        <id>4</id>
        <title>Example 4</title>
        <status>3</status>
        <my_status>6</my_status>
    </element>
    <element>
        <id>5</id>
        <title>Example 5</title>
        <status>1</status>
        <my_status>6</my_status>
    </element>
</mylist>
```

**PHP:**

```
$crawler = new Crawler();
$crawler->addXmlContent($data);

$result = $crawler->filterXPath('/mylist/element[not(status=3) and my_status=6]/title/text()');
```

The elements nodes needs to satisfy some conditions, so calling `$result->count()` should print `2` (Example 3 & Example 5), but it prints 0.

Comment: If that solves your problem, then you have a different XML structure.

Answer (score 1):

The `XPath` should be:

```php
$result = $crawler->filterXPath('//mylist/element[not(status=3) and my_status=6]/title/text()');
```

as per OP @allnex's prior edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

From filteXpath annotation

```
 * The XPath expression is evaluated in the context of the crawler, which
 * is considered as a fake parent of the elements inside it.
 * This means that a child selector "div" or "./div" will match only
 * the div elements of the current crawler, not their children.
```

Then inside method `$xpath = $this->relativize($xpath);` is applied where your path is modified.

For me most simple solution was just to use relative path like `./mylist`.

But if you can understand what's going on here https://github.com/symfony/dom-crawler/blob/master/Crawler.php#L958 absolute path should be possible, I think